# Converting JavaScript function to Java

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I want to change this code from JavaScript to Java servlet. Can anyone guide me in finding the solution?

```
 var dob1 =  document.getElementById(id).value;
 var today = new Date(),
 dob = new Date(dob1),
 age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean Javascript? Retagging.

Comment: Isn't JavaScript instead of HTML... or simply in which language is written the code you provide ? look a mix of JS/Java

Comment: no i wanted to use this function in java servlet.So i wanted the java servlet code for this

Comment: with servlet, for first line of code you would need to do request.getParameter("name of field"); Servlets dont have the option to pick something with id. After that, SimpleDateFormat and Date class would get you going.

Comment: The DOM access might be a bit tricky from as servlet, why don't you state the goal of the servlet instead? Is it to calculate age based on a http parameter or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) API.

```
String dobString = "1978-03-26";
Date dobDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dobString);

Calendar dobCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dobCalendar.setTime(dobDate);
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int age = -1;

while (today.after(dobCalendar)) {
    age++;
    today.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
}

System.out.println(age); // 32
```

Since the `Calendar` API is horrible, I'd suggest [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead.

```
String dobString = "1978-03-26";
DateTime dobDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parseDateTime(dobString);
DateTime today = new DateTime();
int age = Years.yearsBetween(dobDate, today).getYears();
System.out.println(age); // 32
```

Comment: i m using datepicker and also date format for this.I have implemented this in jsp code and i want to implement the same code in servlet

Comment: OK. What stops you from doing this? (note that JSP != JavaScript)

Comment: yeah i know that. Let me give u my jsp code and servlet code.

Comment: function getAge(id) {

   getFormattedDate(id);
 
  var dob1 =  document.getElementById(id).value;
  var today = new Date(),
            dob = new Date(dob1),
            age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;
  
  document.getElementById('age').value = age;
  
}

Comment: Here is an Ant file which converts JSP code to Servlet (I havent tried on my own). You should go through some jsp/servlet tutorials. http://www.arulraj.net/2010/04/jsp-to-servlet-converter.html

Comment: <tr>
                    <td align="right" >
                        <fmt:message key="global.dob"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <input type="text" size="20" id="datepicker" readonly name="dob" onchange="getAge('datepicker');" value="<%= pInfo.getStrDob() %>" />
                   
                       <fmt:message key="global.age"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="text" size="4" id="age" readonly name="age"  value="" />
                   </td>
                </tr>

Comment: Isn't your sole problem after all just the passing of input value as request parameter to the servlet? Use `onchange="submit()"` and grab it as request parameter the usual way. If you want to do this without page refresh, then you'll need to learn ajax. As to the servlet tutorials, I strongly recommend to look in servlets tag info page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info to get the concepts straight and find links to right learning resources.

Comment: String dateFormat = (String) session.getAttribute("calendarDateFormat");
 session.setAttribute("calendarDateFormat", dateFormat);
       
String strDob = request.getParameter("dob");
 Date dob = ApplicationUtils.getSqlDateFromString(dateFormat, strDob);
regStrDate = request.getParameter("regStrDate");
 Date regstrDate = ApplicationUtils.getSqlDateFromString(dateFormat, regStrDate);
  whereClause = " cd.datepicker_date='" + regstrDate + "'";
 int regStrDateId = dateTimePickerImpl.getCalendarDateDetailsByWhereClause(whereClause).get(0).getDatepickerId();
 patientInfo.setDob(dob);
           
;

Comment: @yopirates: I'd also read up how Stackoverflow works ... There's no need to post code clutter in comments. Either update your question to include the necessary information, or ask a new question if it concerns a **different problem** than asked in the initial question.